# Can I simplify this jQuery where I look for elements on a form?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way that I can simplify this code:

```
var topic_html = obj.$form.find("#select-topic").html();
var topic_val = obj.$form.find("#select-topic").val();
var topic_text = obj.$form.find("#select-topic option:selected").text();
```

I know it's fairly clean but is there a way that I can avoid the three instances of `obj.$form.find.`

Comment: i think there is not any way to simplify

Comment: Perhaps a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Since the lookups are by IDs there really is no difference between obj.$form.find and $('#select-topic').val();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need find the select each time, cache it in a variable.

```
var topic = obj.$form.find("#select-topic");
var topic_html = topic.html();
var topic_val = topic.val();
var topic_text = topic.find("option:selected").text();
```

Comment: I would use `var $topic =` in my code, just to remind myself its a JQuery object, but this is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting an object by its id - why are you doing `obj.$form.find`?

Just do `$('#select-topic')` - unless you need to make sure the element is a child of the form?

Anyway:

```
var select = $('#select-topic');
var topic_html = select.html();
var topic_val = select.val();
var topic_text = select.find('option:selected').text();
```

Why do you need all three versions of the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slight variation to @xdazz's answer. I try to keep it to a single var keyword.

```
var topic = obj.$form.find("#select-topic"),
    topic_html = topic.html(),
    topic_val = topic.val(),
    topic_text = topic.find("option:selected").text();
```